# Gmail Schema Whitelist Request - No working email adress

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, schema, whitelist

I have a very specific problem with the [Gmail Schema Whitelist Request](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) process. Based on the guideline I should send a real-life email coming from my production servers including the markup / schema to schema.whitelisting+sample@gmail.com. Unfortunately my product does not allow the specific email adress from google, I guess because of the plus character ("+"), for registering. I want to trigger a confirmation email ([One-Click Action](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/one-click-action#confirm_action): [confirmaction](/questions/tagged/confirmaction)). Any suggestions how to go on?

Comment: Support `+` in your product as a valid email address character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per advised before by the support, I tried to send my sample to `schema.whitelisting@gmail.com`. You can try sending your sample there too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this. We will try it out next!

Comment: Update: We could contact the whitelisting team with the email adress you shared! Thanks a lot!